# Create an alarm for the metric "StatusCheckFailed" in the script using CLI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using cloud watch CLI to write a script . As part of this script I need to create an alarm when the status check fails.
Steps followed -
1) First I create a launch config for an AMI 
2) Then autoscaling group, scale up policy.
3) Now , I need to create a alarm such that when an instance belonging to Ami ( from step 1) fails, then raise an alarm which essentially creates a new instance.

I am having issues with creating an alarm for the same. Help appreciated.

mon-put-metric-alarm TestAlarm --comparisonoperator LessThanToThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --metric-name StatusCheckFailed --namespace "AWS/EC2" --period 600 --statistic Average --threshold 1 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:TestInstance --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=TestAutoScalingGroup"

The error received is Status Check failed not recognized.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

mon-put-metric-alarm AuthServerAlarm  --comparison-operator  GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold  --evaluation-periods  1 --region us-west-1 --metric-name  StatusCheckFailed_Any  --namespace  "AWS/EC2"  --period  600  --statistic Average --threshold  1 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-1:13445335:scalingPolicy:1234:newGuid:autoScalingGroupName/TestAutoScalingGroup:policyName/LaunchNewInstance,arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:123:Test --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupNameTestAutoScalingGroup"